# Wait x seconds before grabing page cotent with file_get_contents or Curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm fetching a page content using file_get_contents of the following url:
http://www.reedalcantara.com.br/pt-br/Eventos/Expositores/

Everything works fine but the results are paginated and this pagination was built using ajax. I've tried to use the url with the "show all" parameter:
http://www.reedalcantara.com.br/pt-br/Eventos/Expositores/#search=rpp%3D64

The problem is: if you test the url on your browser, you will notice that the website first load the page with 12 results and after 1 or 2 seconds it reloads with all results on it.
Is there anyway to wait some seconds using php functions before fetching the content?
I really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: The real problem here is that JavaScript is executed, not the time that passes. You can either simulate that ajax or use a browser like phantomjs if you can use JS instead of PHP

Comment: How can I simulate that ajax? The problem is that it took me almost a month to code everything and now I have 1 week to integrate the data into the website. I will not have time to build it again in js! :(

Comment: You can simulate the ajax by using cURL and two consecutive calls, from what I see this is also what @blue112 suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything rendered/queried using JS won't get fetch by `file_get_contents`.

What you need, if you want to go that way, is to figure out the URL the JS is querying to show the result (using Firebug or Chrome Dev Console, for instance) and to query that URL yourself.

Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: What if it is a POST request?

Comment: You can create a post request using CURL. I don't think `file_get_contents` will let you post data.

Comment: Do you know on which tab should I look o chrome dev to get this information? Also, I don't need to post any data, just to get the results that are displayed on page.